# CoreData on a distant server syncronizing between different clients (apps)

Tags: iphone, web-services, cocoa, macos, core-data

I'd know if it exists a kind of CoreData server ?

The point is to get an "automatic API server" providing data to clients.

It can be useful to implement **very quickly** standalone Forum app, Games or anything on the cloud...

Comment: PS : I know I can install another SQL server. I can write an REST/XML API etc. But that is not the question, right ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a Core Data server.

Strictly speaking Core Data isn't a data base system but rather an object-graph management system with persistence tools added on. It's primary purpose is to handle the complexity of object relationships internal to a single app. You don't even have to save the graph to disk if you don't want to.

NextStep/Apple used to have a nifty technology called Enterprise Objects which was a kind of object oriented wrapper for non-OOP databases. It did allow you to setup or interface with any database no matter how heavy weight. Unfortunately, they have stopped selling it and just use it internally now. It was rather nifty.